# VS2010 SP1 Combobox displaymember issue

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I have a problem with a Displaymember of Combobox in VS 2010 and C#.
I have one table as T1 with parent id as int and some other information and another table as T2 with id as int and Name as varchar(50). I want to use T2 as a references.
So, my combobox:
Binded - T1
Datasource - T2
DisplayMember - T2.Name
ValueMember - T2.Id

It does not wont to work and I do not see where I did a mistake.
Also, if i do like this:
DisplayMember - T2.Id
ValueMember - T2.Id
than it start working.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a code example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I did not add any code for that. Everything set in design time.

Comment: Forgot to mention it is a WinForm

Comment: Can you share your codes how did you populate your `combobox`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties to the name of two fields present in the second table.
`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are strings that should refer to fields present in the table binded to the DataSource property.
If you bind the datasource to a table that doesn't contains the fields listed for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` nothing could work as intended

If your tables are related by the ParentID and ID fields then you could create a datasource using JOIN expression

```
SELECT t1.ParentID, t1.Field1, t1.Field2, t2.ID, t2.Name
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.ParentID = t2.ID
```

then you could set the DisplayMember and ValueMember of your combobox

```
combobox1.DisplayMember = "t2.Name";
combobox1.ValueMember = "t2.ID";
```

Comment: I can not do that. I'm using 2 SPs to get data. And why if I change DisplayMember to T2.Id it start working?

Comment: OK, but which is the schema that you bind to the datasource property of the combobox? The strings used for Diplay and Value should be the names of columns present in that schema.

Comment: It is a SP2 that brings columns Id and Name (what I called T2)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I add a picture, so it will be self explained?

Comment: You can't with your reputation, edit your question and post a link to a shared service. (photobucket.com, tinypic.com etc)

Comment: Thanks
[Picture of a ComboBox Issue](http://i1302.photobucket.com/albums/ag137/Rob-08520/ComboBox_zps71d6eec4.jpg)

Comment: From what I see there is nothing to cause this behavior. Perhaps something in the BindingSource objects.

Comment: [ComboBox with bindingSource](http://i1302.photobucket.com/albums/ag137/Rob-08520/ComboBox1_zps2b8cfb53.jpg) 
Also, when I add a new line and choose Id from ComboBox it is not letting me go anywhere else. Looks like I violate some rules.